# Значение термина pattern в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Помогите найти пожалуйста доступное определение термина pattern

Comment: Где Вы встречали этот термин, покажите ссылки, примеры?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach https://habr.com/post/309422/

Comment: Спасибо, завтра ознакомлюсь, но скорее всего это паттерны программирования возможно в контексте реакта

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, Все, нашел, загуглив по другому, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Па́ттерн (англ. 'pattern — образец, шаблон, система) — заимствованное слово. Слово «pattern» используется как термин в нескольких западных дисциплинах и технологиях, откуда оно и проникло в русскоязычную среду. Смысл термина «паттерн» всегда у́же чем просто «образец», и варьируется в зависимости от области знаний, в которой используется. 
Паттерн (информатика) — эффективный способ решения характерных задач проектирования, в частности проектирования компьютерных программ.